# Ошибка при чтении данных через HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android-studio

Добрый день! При попытке чтения данных при помощи HttpURLConnection возникает ошибка, смысл которой уловить не могу.Точнее не понимаю что она выводит, и куда копать..

Права на доступ к интеренту в androidmanifest.xml прописаны

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.укаук.noc.nocmessages">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <activity android:name=".Form1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Класс который собственно не работает:

```
public class jsonnoc {
    public void GetJsonMet(String stget){
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        Log.d("неашипка", "--пробую почитать json");
        try {
            Log.d("неашипка", "--1");
            URL url = new URL("http://noc.укаукау.ru/getjsonmess.php");
            Log.d("неашипка", "--2");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("неашипка", "--3");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Log.d("неашипка", "--4");
            urlConnection.connect();
            Log.d("неашипка", "--5");


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ашипка", "--не смогли прочитать JSON");
        }
    }
}
```

Его использование:

```
     jsonnoc jsn=new jsonnoc();
     jsn.GetJsonMet("{'userlogin':'login'}");
```

Что пишет logcat:

```
06-07 15:53:25.061 28781-28781/ru.ука.noc.nocmessages D/неашипка: --пробую почитать json
06-07 15:53:25.061 28781-28781/ru.укаук.noc.nocmessages D/неашипка: --1
06-07 15:53:25.061 28781-28781/ru.куа.noc.nocmessages D/неашипка: --2
06-07 15:53:25.072 28781-28781/ru.укау.noc.nocmessages D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-07 15:53:25.076 28781-28781/ru.ука.noc.nocmessages D/неашипка: --3
06-07 15:53:25.076 28781-28781/ru.укаук.noc.nocmessages D/неашипка: --4
06-07 15:53:25.083 28781-28781/ru.укаук.noc.nocmessages W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.укау.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.ука.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.ука.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.ука.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.ккк.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.dfv.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at ru.dfvd.noc.nocmessages.jsonnoc.GetJsonMet(jsonnoc.java:28)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at ru.dfv.noc.nocmessages.Form1.ClickEnterNocButton(Form1.java:36)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.javaк22429)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-07 15:53:25.090 28781-28781/ru.к.noc.nocmessages D/ашипка: --не смогли прочитать JSON
```

В чем я не прав?

Answer (score 0):

Подобные запросы необходимо оформалять через AsyncTask. Например так:

```
    public void ClickEnterNocButton(View view) {

        Log.d("неашипка", "--click!");
        AddToLog("clear");

        EditText elogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText epass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        AddToLog("-пробуем залогиниться");
        // jsonnoc jsn=new jsonnoc();
        //jsn.GetJsonMet("{'userlogin':'login'}");
        new GetMyDataFromUrl().execute("!!!!!!!!!");

        AddToLog("-сохраняем настройки");

        SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit = mSettings.edit();
        mEdit.putString("userlogin", elogin.getText().toString());
        mEdit.commit();
        mEdit.apply();
        mEdit.putString("userpass", epass.getText().toString());
        mEdit.commit();
        mEdit.apply();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form1);
        AddToLog("-читаем настройки");

        EditText elogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText epass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        elogin.setText(mSettings.getString("userlogin", ""));
        epass.setText(mSettings.getString("userpass", ""));

        AddToLog(elogin.getText().toString());
        AddToLog(epass.getText().toString());

    }

    class GetMyDataFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            Log.d("неашипка", "--пробую почитать json");
            try {
                Log.d("неашипка", "--1");
                URL url = new URL("http://noc.укаука.ru/getjsonmess.php");
                Log.d("неашипка", "--2");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.d("неашипка", "--3");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                Log.d("неашипка", "--4");
                urlConnection.connect();
                Log.d("неашипка", "--5");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("ашипка", "--не смогли прочитать JSON");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```